# Number Theory Books

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations, book-recommendation

I'm interested in general in all number theory, but especially in solving diophantine equations and expressions with $\bmod$. Someone can advise me few books or web sites where I could find more?

I have found the book: "Fundamentals of number theory" (William J.LeVeque, 1977). It's good?

Comment: Classic is Hardy and Wright

Comment: Yes, it can be very good because I can find it also in pdf. Are there latest publications?

Comment: You have two specific courses in number theory, analytical and algebraic theory. In the first you have the book of T. M. Apostol and in the second you have two volumes of Ian Stewart, both very interesting. And as an excellent introduction is the book Foundations of the Theory of numbers of I.M. Vinográdov. But there are many more that are recommended.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_Introduction_to_the_Theory_of_Numbers), *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers*

is a classic book in the field of number theory, by G. H. Hardy and E. M. Wright.

The fourth edition (1975 printing) is available [on line](https://archive.org/details/Hardy_and_Wright_-_Introduction_to_the_Theory_of_Numbers/page/n3).

The updated sixth edition was published in 2008.

Answer (score 1):

I have always found Burton's number theory book "just right" for a first course in elementary number theory; in addition, he has, in my opinion, an extremely well written, informative, book on the history of mathematics.

If you are a more advanced student, you may find Hardy and Wright more agreeable, but if not, Burton's text might be a good place to start. I have found his explanations to be comprehensive and clear.

Answer (score 0):

please see [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Olympiad_books) and [here](https://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=347&lmm=0) in Number Theory section.